# How to resolve SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have two entities, Match and Team, problem is in mapping (i guess), i am not looking for someone to give me solution to this problem, just give me some hint where should i look in documentation. For some reason i got stuck on this and can't find solution.. I will provide code of my two entities.
Match.php

```
/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Team", inversedBy="matchOne")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_one_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $teamOne;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Team", inversedBy="matchTwo")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_two_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $teamTwo;
```

Team.php

```
/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Match", mappedBy="teamOne")
 */
protected $matchOne;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Match", mappedBy="teamTwo")
 */
protected $matchTwo;
```

Problem is in my form type when i query for match, here is part of code

```
->add('match', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Match',
        'choice_label' => 'getMatch',
        ] )
```

And getMatch function

```
public function getMatch() {
    return $this->getTeamOne()->getName() . ' - ' . $this->getTeamTwo()->getName();
}
```

Form type is for creating new bet, obviously i want to show matches (team names, example: Chelsea - Liverpool) in drop down and write id of that match to bet entity.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in table name. Match is reserved word in MySQL. So everyone who experience same or similar problem please first check if your table names might be reserved word. I lost one whole day on this and every time i have some problem like this it is something stupid like this...